# Input Selection (Not Telling/Male/Female) in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry if this is a too easy question but it's bugging me.

I need to create a simple selection field for

- Not Telling
- Male
- Female

and the default when not entered to be "Not "Telling".

Do i just run a migration like:

```
rails g migration AddGenderToListings gender:select
```

and then in my Profile Edit Form

```
<%= f.select :gender, [["Not Telling", 1], ["Male", 2], ["Female", 3]] %>
```

But how do i display it afterwards on a show page ??

if just **<%= @user.gender %>** it puts the number of the selection.

Any enlightenment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new migration to set default value

Or rollback your migration, change it to

```
add_column :listings, :gender, :integer, :default => 1
```

And migrate again

**EDIT**
In model you can add

```
def gender_txt
  ["Not Telling", "Male", "Female"][self.gender - 1]
end
```

In your views, you can display using

```
@user1.gender_txt
@user2.gender_txt
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. But how do i display the gender afterwards on a show page? @user.gender just puts the number of the selection.

Comment: You could do something like `["Not Telling", "Male", "Female"][@user.gender - 1]`.

Comment: A lot of Users can set their gender, how do i display them rendering the selction. Just delete the numbers in my edit form? Or do i not getting you right. What should be the code for the Gender display ?

Comment: You can define an `Array` or `Hash` in user model, which has the Strings. Now you can access them using key or index, which is the num that is stored in database.

Comment: sry but im little new to rails. Do you mind editing your answer ? :)

Answer (score 2):

In your model you can add:

```
GENDER_TYPES = ["Not telling","Male", "Female"]
```

Then in your form:

```
<%= f.select :gender,  User::GENDER_TYPES %>
```

The above is a simple fix that worked for me.